# Qual é a lógica de um carrinho de compras?

Tags: php, session

Estou aprendendo programação e quero tentar fazer um sistema de carrinho de compras em `PHP` que adiciona os produtos no carrinho e finaliza o pedido. Pelo que eu andei vendo, parece que esse tipo de sistema usa `muito` do recurso de `array multidimensional` para ligar o comprador aos produtos.

Qual o tipo de dados usados para dizer `que um pedido tem x produtos e pertence a fulano de tal`? Alguém teria disponibilidade de me explicar um pouca a lógica desse tipo de sistema?

Comment: Podes usar a session para manter os produtos no carrinho de compras do utilizador. A session no PHP contém, normalmente os teus dados de sessão como Nome e login, mas também pode conter dados de outras coisas. Não convém é sobrecarregar muito a session. Mas para um carrinho de compras serve perfeitamente.

Answer (score 2):

> Numa loja virtual, por exemplo, o foco é vender. Um usuário coloca
>   coisas no carrinho e por algum motivo fechou o browser. Quando ele
>   voltar nesse site terá que refazer toda a compra, buscar os produtos e
>   colocá-los no carrinho. Nesse processo o usuário pode ficar impaciente
>   e desistir de comprar. Se o site tivesse recurso de salvar o carrinho
>   e identificar o cliente mesmo que não esteja logado, teria maior
>   chance de concretizar a venda sem aborrecê-lo.

Apenas copiei o trecho de uma outra resposta. O original pode ver aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/119365/4793

Frizando novamente, a decisão depende de cada caso. Independente do foco ser para vendas, as vezes, salvar o carrinho em banco de dados pode não ser ideal.

Particularmente recomendo que salve os dados mesmo que o usuário não esteja autenticado pois esses dados são úteis para gerar estatísticas e entender melhor o comportamento dos usuários. Assim você pode estudar formas de melhorar as vendas. Pois como citei diversas vezes, o foco é vender.

Na parte técnica, falando em códigos, pense em como montar a estrutura.

Evite coisas fracas ou bagunçadas como

```
$_SESSION = array(
    'id do produto' => array('nome do produto', 'valor', 'quantidade')
)
```

Pois na variável global $_SESSION pode ter outros dados não referentes ao carrinho como o id do usuário autenticado.

Então pelo menos monte algo mais organizado como

```
$_SESSION['id da loja']['cart'] = array(
    'id do produto' => array('nome do produto', 'valor', 'quantidade')
)
```

se usa o session para autenticar, então monte algo assim

```
$_SESSION['user']['id usuario'] = 'um token'
```

Assim evitará conflitos e permitirá flexibilidade.

Mas o ideal é salvar apenas um token também para o cart.

```
$_SESSION['id da loja']['cart'] = 'token do cart';
```

Esse token seria então relacionado com uma tabela no banco de dados

```
tabela cart
   id_loja
   id_usuario
   cart_token

tabela cart_items
   id_item
   item_valor
   item_quantidade
   id_qualquer_outra_coisa_que_precisar
```

Mas ao invés de usar session para guardar o token, use cookie

```
$_COOKIE['id da loja']['cart'] = 'token do cart';
```

pois como mencionado acima, usando o cookie, poderá permitir que o usuário restaure o carrinho de compras se por algum motivo fechar o browser.

Answer (score 0):

penso que a melhor opção seria ires guardando os produtos para a base de dados por exemplo numa tabela carrinho ( codigo_carrinho pk, produto ... etc ) assim podias associar esse carrinho a um utilizador por exemplo o joaquim tem o carro1 e quando fazes um pedido vais buscar os dados dos 2 e preenches, sendo que tens de ter cuidado com vários aspectos, como guardar um carrinho no produto á 5 meses e ele sofrer uma alteraçao de valor !, tens de pensar um pouco primeiro no que queres guardar no carrinho. espero ter ajudado xD tamb sou novato mas tenho feito um carrinho +- dessa maneira. qualquer coisa estou por ai ... abraço ;)

Answer (score -2):

Boa tarde!

Sei que este post é antigo, mas vejo que há muita gente entrando, e talvez, essa seja uma dúvida de pessoas hoje em dia.

Para criar um carrinho de compras, você pode utilizar diversas maneiras para criar a aplicação em PHP.

Basicamente, você precisará ter um botão de compra que ao ser clicado ele armazene em uma tabela do banco de dados o id do produto ou pode também, se desejar, acrescentar outras informações pertinentes ao produto, ser gravado a sessão, data/hora, e outras informações desejadas.

Quando usuário clicar no botão deverá ser criado uma sessão, que normalmente eu chamo de cart, e toda vez que você clicar no botão de comprar, o sistema deve verificar se essa sessão "cart" existe ou não, se existe permanece com a sessão, caso contrário, deve ser criada.

No carrinho de compras, você vai puxar o pedido, listando os produtos referente a sessão, ou seja, ao fazer a consulta você utilizará no where  a coluna onde você armazenou a sessão e aí basta disponibilizar ao usuário se quer excluir o produto daquele pedido ou alterar a quantidade, entre outras.

Para fazer o valor total, normalmente você vai criar uma varíavel que iremos denominar aqui como total e irá criar ela com valor zero antes do for ou foreach, e dentro da estrutura de repetição você menciona ela dessa maneira:
$total += $value-do-foreach['coluna-com-valor-do-produto'];

Dessa maneira, o valor vai ser somado a medida em que o laço de repetição será executado pela aplicação.

Você deixar uma playlist no Youtube de como criar um carrinho de compras, acho que vai ajudar as pessoas na construção do seu próprio carrinho de compras:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TTMLMIfHud8&list=PLVR6F4yZo5Lk-5Qo_6E-dp6gmKIwWCSjn