# Qual a melhor maneira de persistir dados em uma aplicação?

Tags: php

Em um CRUD de empresa por exemplo, muitas vezes encontramos formulários extensos, com muitos campos e provavelmente o usuário vai esquecer ou preencher algum(ns) de maneira incorreta, então ao dar submit no formulário qual é a melhor maneira de salvar e reescrever os dados digitados, caso haja erro, para que não seja preciso preencher o formulário do zero novamente?

Penso em algumas soluções:

- Usar variáveis de sessão para armazenar todos os dados digitados e para reescreve-los verificar se a variável existe e então escreve-la no documento.
- Fazer todo o submit por Ajax, não recarregar a página ao dar submit, mas sim, enviar os dados para a validação. (porém me parece que a aplicação perde desempenho).
- Validar tudo com Javascript, embora alguns campos precisarão realizar consultas no banco de dados para serem validados.

Essas são as maneiras que consigo imaginar, mas não sei qual seria a mais rentável para a agilidade do software, e se há outras formas. Qual seria a melhor e que daria menos dor de cabeça?

Comment: Outra pergunta negativada em massa, na minha opinião, uma pergunta válida. Não é baseada em opiniões, e sim para descobrir qual maneira é mais usada, pois muitas pessoas tem essa dúvida e a mesma pode ter várias formas de se fazer, então assim pegaria a forma que mais acharia usável.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sua pergunta, sugere muitas respostas, no entanto, uma boa forma de resolver isso. É usando exceções. Exemplo:

```
<?php
class Form
{
    private $data = array();
    public $html;

    public function validationForm()
    {
      $errors = array();
       try {

         if ($this->data['nome'] == '') {
            $errors[] = 'O nome não pode ficar em branco!';
         }
          if ($this->data['email'] == '') {
            $errors[] = 'O email não pode ficar em branco!';
         }
         $totalErrors = count($errors);
         if ($totalErrors) {
              $exception = new Exception('errors');
              $exception->setParams(array('status' => false,'title'=>$totalErrors.' erros:', 'errors' => $errors, 'collection' => $this->data);
              throw exception;
         }

         return array(
           'status'=>true,
           'collection' => $this->data
         )

       } catch(Exception $e) {

         return $e->getMessage();

       }
    }

    public function renderForm()
    {
        if ($_POST) {
          $this->data = $_POST;
          $validation = $this->validationForm();
        }

        $form = array(
                'formName' => 'teste',
                'id' => 'teste',
                'method' => 'post',
                'action' => '?send',
                'inputs' =>
                    array(
                    'label' => 'Nome:'
                    'type'  => 'text',
                    'name'  => 'nome',
                    'id'    => 'nome',
                    ),
                    array(
                    'label' => 'Email:'
                    'type'  => 'text',
                    'name'  => 'email',
                    'id'    => 'nome',
                    ),
                    array(
                    'type' => 'submit',
                    'value' => 'Enviar',
                    'name' => 'enviar'
                    )
        );

        $this->html = '';
         if (!$validation['status']) {
             $this->data = $validation['collection'];
             $this->html .= '<div class="erros">
                              '.$validation['title'].'
                                <ul>
                              ';
               foreach ($validation['errors'] as $erro){
                   $this->html .= '<li>- '.$erro.'</li>';
               }                  
             $this->html .= '
                                </ul>
                              </div>';
         } else {
         //grava os dados
            var_dump($validation['collection']);
         }
        $this->html .= '<form name="'.$form['formName'].'" id="'.$form['id'].'" action="'.$form['action'].'" method="'.$form['method'].'">';
        foreach ($form['inputs'] as $input) {
           $value = (isset($input['value'])) ? $input['value'] : '';
            $this->html .= '<label>'.$input['label'].'</label>
              <input type="'.$input['type'].'" name="'.$input['name'].'" "'.$input['id'].'" value="'.$value.'">';
        }
        $this->html .= '</form>';
        return $this->html;
    }
} 
$form = new Form();
echo $form->renderForm();
```

Answer (score 1):

Sempre que pensar "qual o melhor para fazer X ou Y", troque essa pergunta para "quais os meios recomendados para fazer X sob o contexto tal e tal".

Dizer que X é melhor ou que Y é melhor é algo pretencioso e equivocado pois tudo depende do contexto ao qual se aplica.

Falando diretamente sobre o assunto da questão, a forma básica, simples e segura é salvar em cookies.

Mas veja que isso dependerá do contexto.

O formulário possui dados sensíveis? (cartão de crédito, senha, coisas do tipo).

Claro que se possuir dados desse tipo, não salve-os em cookie. Salve apenas o que não for sensível ou use outro meio como variáveis de sessão em conjunto com cookies.

Enfim, isso depende muito do contexto. Numa loja virtual, por exemplo, o foco é vender. Um usuário coloca coisas no carrinho e por algum motivo fechou o browser. Quando ele voltar nesse site terá que refazer toda a compra, buscar os produtos e colocá-los no carrinho. Nesse processo o usuário pode ficar impaciente e desistir de comprar. Se o site tivesse recurso de salvar o carrinho e identificar o cliente mesmo que não esteja logado, teria maior chance de concretizar a venda sem aborrecê-lo.

Como pode ver, esse foi um exemplo dentro de um contexto específico de um shopping cart. E ainda assim há formas diferentes de resolver.

Comment: O único problema de usar cookies é que ele pode estar desativado, logo não funcionaria naquele navegador com configurações para desativa-los.

Comment: Não se preocupe com isso. Pois quem desativa cookie ou javascript o faz deliberadamente. Na prática, não conseguirá usar os serviços em quase nenhum website. O que podefazer é detectar se cookie está ativado. Se não estiver, emita um aviso para que o usuário tenha cieência de que poderá perder tudo o que digitou numa eventual falha.

Comment: Apenas salientando novamente que a resposta é genérica e na verdade não responde nada com nada devido a sua pergunta que é muito genérica.