# PHP - website e-commerce, gerar UUID para Cada carrinho de compras

Tags: php, programação-funcional

Bom dia antes de mais, estou a tentar criar um código único para cada carrinho de compras, qual a melhor maneira, eu estava a pensar em usar UUID, mas não tenho a minima ideia de como o fazer, se alguem souber um bom forum que fale sobre isso estao a vontade obrigado ;)

Comment: coincidência.. é quase relacionado a isso: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/80604/qual-%C3%A9-a-l%C3%B3gica-de-um-carrinho-de-compras

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Algo simples e funcional é usar a informação do timestamp

```
$token = microtime();
```

Retornará algo assim

```
0.13287600 1460718460
```

Se não quiser o caracter de espaço pode gerar assim também:

```
$token = microtime(true);
```

Retornará algo como: `1460718491.9867`

Claro que se esse uuid/token for acessível publicamente, é recomendável encriptá-lo pelo menos para impedir de alguém entender como o token é gerado.  Nesse exemplo, usando timestamp qualquer programador consegue advinhar que o formato é um timestamp e com isso pode conseguir fazer um sequestro de token. Por isso, se usar um sequência muito óbvia, criptografe-a.

```
$token = hash('sha256', microtime(true));
//gera algo como `6d20018cf7023becaf77a2e0dc5d4034894aebdde9febb093f83dbcc3744bce0`
```